# Fuse two images in one by removing parallax

Tags: image-processing, parallax

I am looking for technique to fuse two images from two distant cameras by removing [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). Distance between cameras and angle of view are known.
[image: Expected result] is in the middle.